# IIS Application Pool Identity User not created or available until website starts

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm trying to add an Application Pool Identity user to folder permissions in Windows Server 2012 Standard, Build 9200. This is IIS 8.0.

When I try to add the user `IIS APPPOOL\ExampleAppPoolIdentity` Windows reports that the Name is not found. All Object types are selected, and Locations is set to the local machine.

I am adding the permissions through `folder properties -> security -> edit -> add`

If I set a website or web application to point to the Application Pool, and browse to the site, the user is then created/available and works when adding to folder permissions.

I have tried this on my local version of Windows 7 with IIS 7.5 and the behaviour is that as soon as the Application Pool is created the user is created and ready to add as permissions to a folder. I have also not had this problem with IIS 7.5 before on other Windows environments including 2012.

My end goal is to programmatically add the permissions to the folder, and I have had the same trouble using `Microsoft.Web.Administration` to create the Application Pool and then translate that to a user SID with `System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate`. However, this question is purely an operating system question at this point, as I can't achieve the same result through the standard Windows GUI.

Is there a way I can force the creation/availability of the Application Pool Identity user without first running a website that is pointing to the Application Pool?

Comment: Have you looked into ASP.NET MVC technology yet? I'm not a developer but I've configured many web servers for many apps using MVC that seemed to help them standardize and simplify the app level security using it. Just a quick thought without connecting and checking server settings, etc. on applicable web servers in my environments I administer and maintain.

Comment: @JUICED_IT Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not sure how it addresses the question though. Perhaps if you specifically build an ASP.NET MVC website and install it (through an installer?) on a live box, it automatically makes the App Pool Identity user available on the correct folder? Is that what you're saying? Unfortunately I'm not building an ASP.NET MVC web site here.